# What date formats does Excel recognize as dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

What date formats will Excel recognize as dates?

I've been using `Jul 30/10 11:41:10` but Excel doesn't recognize this as a date.

I don't want to apply a function to the value, I just want to open the CSV file in Excel and "have it work".  So I can change the format as needed, just want to know what the valid date format options are.

Comment: what system locale do you have? I think, you must enter the date according to your locale.

Answer (score 2):

Netme is correct, the options are based on your locale.

If you click on a cell in Excel, and hit `CTRL+1` (format cells), then go to the first tab and select the DATE category, it will list the valid options.  It will also give you option to  change locales.

edit - What is your source file?  I know you said CSV but what system does it originate from?